# JOB TALEND TRIGGER

Tags: database, postgresql, integration, talend

I've a question about Talend, I want to insert data in csv in real time after each inserting in PostgreSql database. Have you ideas ? 
Thank you !

[My Job TALEND](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlWBz.png)

Comment: Can you please show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot trigger Talend's operation from database. 
If your table is very intensively written - so all the exercise does not make any sense at all. If the inserts are relatively rare - i would recommend to create a postgreSQL trigger, to populate table with PK of a new record. Talend job will pick the newly inserted records, by probing that new table, let's say every second, and will delete that Pk.